# "this" is not defined in event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> why this is not defined in function increaseCounter but is defined in getBadgeClass function ?

```
<button onClick = { this.increaseCounter } className = { 
this.getBadgeClasses() }>increment</button>

getBadgeClasses() {         
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
}

 increaseCounter(){
    this.state.count++;
}
```

Comment: Calling context is different. Try `onClick={()=>this.increaseCounter()}` or `onClick={ this.increaseCounter.bind(this)}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: And don't assign to state like `this.state.count++;` instead use `this.setState(prevState => ({count:prevState.count + 1}));`

Answer (score 5):

You should bind function which uses `this`. To save `this` context you can use one of these ways:
1) Bind functions in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.getBadgeClasses = this.getBadgeClasses.bind(this);
  this.increaseCounter = this.increaseCounter.bind(this);
}
```

2) Or you can use arrow function. It saves `this` context as well:

```
increaseCounter = () => {
 ...your code
}
```

You can read more here: https://medium.com/silesis/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb#4803

Answer (score 1):

When the interpreter reaches the component, **this.getBadgeClasses()** executes right away. It is called on the object referred by **this** so the keyword **this** inside the function, points to the same object. So it is able to resolve the reference to the state.

On the other hand, **this.increaseCounter()** does not execute right away. The attribute onClick just stores a reference to that function. Whenever a user clicks on the button, that referenced function is called on the global object. So the keyword **this** is set to undefined in the strict mode. To resolve this, you have to bind the **increaseCounter()** to **this** in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind `this` to `increaseCounter` function to access `this` object. Do this :

```
<button onClick = { this.increaseCounter.bind(this) } 
        className = { this.getBadgeClasses.bind(this) }
>
    increment
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Shahrukh has mentioned, in strict mode global object refers to undefined in place of the window object. So when the function **increaseCounter()** is called on global object, it calls on an undefined object.

Also, when a function is used as an event handler, its 'this' is set to the element the event fired from. As a DOM event handler. Therefore, **increaseCounter()**'s this is set to global context.

Since in JavaScript class methods are not bound by default unless you specifically bind them, they are just "function objects". Any object or variable can reference the function because it's just a pointer, like any other object.
The question asked is actually to be blamed on JavaScript, not React.js.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this error. The first is that the error handler must be defined like this, in order to make `this` work correctly with the error function:

```javascript
increaseCounter = () => { ... }
```

The second part of the problem is that you can't change the state directly; instead, you must change the state using `this.setState()`:

```javascript
increaseCounter = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {count: prevState.count + 1}
    }
}
```